# Given any $4$ numbers, is there a way to make $24$?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

I was playing the game $24$, and I saw that some numbers, such as $5,8,9,10$, could not be multiplied, divided, subtracted, added, etc. by me to get $24$ no matter *how hard* I tried...

> **Question:** So that got me thinking: Is there a way to tell if a set of $4$ numbers can be manipulated to make $24$?

You can use any operation sign and any operation you would like (meaning you can use $\log$ and derivatives, but using those is probably going to be inefficient).

Comment: Looks like a good problem. (+1)

Comment: Just a note: your four numbers $5,8,9,$ and $10$ cannot make $24$, so you can stop trying ;)

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, I know, it was just a side note

Comment: Isn't this just the knapsack problem in disguise?

Comment: @suomynonA Yeah, don't worry. I gave up right after I posted this problem...

Comment: @JohnDouma Could you please elaborate a bit more on what you meant by "knapsack problem"?

Comment: Google it. It's a classic problem in Computer Science.

Answer (score 2):

If we are allowed to use the Gamma function:

$$\Gamma(5)\cdot(9-8)^{10} = 24$$

or if we can use the factorial and square root:

$$\left(8^{\frac{10}{5\sqrt{9}}}\right)!$$

I can probably think up some more using other special-ish functions. The way I learned $24$ we could use addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, and square roots (and, of course, parentheses). I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to solve it with only those rules, although I'll keep trying.

Edit: We have

$$\sqrt{\left(8\sqrt{9}\right)^{\frac{10}{5}}} = 24$$

which uses only the "expanded standard" rules. It is the "cleanest" in my opinion of the solutions here.

Comment: Hm... I never learned about Gamma function (I'm only a student) but the factorial and square root solution was interesting!

Comment: @Frank I'm only a student too, but you can never be too studenty to learn interesting math concepts. Also, thanks! The factorial function is usually omitted in $24$, if only for the reason that it becomes the find-$4$ game, but since you said we can use any functions I assumed it was fair game.

Comment: $\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$ for $n = 1,2,3,4,\ldots$

Comment: @Frank I just found a "cleaner" solution - see my edit.